# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push'), with yarn

Tags: reactjs, frontend, yarnpkg, web-frontend, yarn-workspaces

I am currently struggling with the error described in the title, I simply cloned a repo from github and tried to run it...and I simply couldn't make it run. I know I messed up chosing CS as my major but please somebody help me because I am going crazy. I am usîng the yarn package manager

[image]

[image]

The code is supposed to work on its own, I tried Yarn, Yarn start and many other things, completely stuck please help

Comment: lol, the error is trying to say that hooks.visibleColumns are undefined means there is nothing in hooks.visibleColumns

Comment: Please add your code as a code block